# How do I attach a scroll event to Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, ace-editor

I am using the Javascript Rich Text Editor, [ACE Editor](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/). I have managed to get most of what I need to do accomplished, but I need to attach a scroll event to the editor.

How do I do that? The API says to use the ScrollBar (http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=api&api=scrollbar), but I cannot figure out how to use it!

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [changeScrollTop](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/edit_session.js#L988) and changeScrollLeft events emitted from `editor.session`
They are used by the editor [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/editor.js#L163)

Comment: Example would be nice.